# Usuários podem editar respostas/perguntas antigas pra por JS, CSS e HTML executáveis?

Tags: debate

Antes dessa funcionalidade ser implementada, usavamos o **JSFiddle** (e similares) para mostrar o código funcionando. Mas agora que existe essa funcionalidade nativa no site podemos editar as respostas/perguntas que virmos que estão nesse antigo padrão?

Eu editei recentemente uma resposta do Sergio e adicionei a funcionalidade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37315/3999

Isso é o correto? Fiz essa pergunta pra saber se é ético fazer isso, apenas para adicionar a funcionalidade (eu creio que fique mais fácil compreensão)

Comment: Eu não vejo problemas se isso realmente melhorar o post. Mas não vejo necessidade de sair editando todos os posts do site pra usar o editor. Isso poluiria a home. Se for algo esporádico, ok.

Comment: Vi essa edição sua e fiquei com uma pulga, legal abrir o tópico aqui. . . . Acho que editar formatação e código de veteranos deve ser feito com luvas de veludo. Se o Serjão não pôs o StackSnippets, suas razões teria ;) Da minha parte, cada tantos dias tento remover algum jsfiddle de uma resposta minha; aliás, acho que já deu a hora.

Answer (score 6):

Eu diria: depende.

Eu uso o jsFiddle diáriamente e acho prático e melhor que a ferramenta do SO. Tem mais funcionalidades como escolher entre muitas bibliotecas, escolher onde o código vai parar (body, head, etc) e juntar ficheiros externos.

Eu agradeço a edição e acrescento do snippet do SO na maioria dos casos, mas se tem link para o jsFiddle gostaria que ele ficásse.

No fundo gostava que se tivesse link para o jsFiddle ele ficásse (mesmo juntando o snippet do SO deixar ficar o jsFiddle). Nos casos em que a resposta não precisar de snippet ele não fosse inserido.

Comment: Compreendo totalmente seu ponto de vista Sergio, por isso realizei essa pergunta! Eu também notei que a ferramenta da uma poluída no corpo da resposta/pergunta. (Me refiro aos botões).

Comment: @NULL a intenção é muito boa. Perguntar aqui para trocarmos ideias é também muito bom! ++

Answer (score 5):

Bom debate. Ainda estou aguardando para ver todos os casos.

Mas eu já poderia pensar em uma separação de casos. Apesar de não gostar de dois pesos e duas medidas, acho que há uma diferença entre um post abandonado ou de um usuário que desconhece o recurso e pode ser beneficiado com a edição e um post de um usuário ativo em todos os sentidos da palavra.

Este usuário sabe que pode fazer isto e sabe como fazer. Se não o fez pode ser por esquecimento, preguiça de fazer agora ou definitiva ou por escolha. Nestes casos acho que seria bom perguntar para o usuário se ele quer que faça por ele em algum caso específico ou em todos seus posts. Não são muitos casos a perguntar.

De qualquer forma deve-se evitar sair editando muitos posts de uma vez só (tem até alguma pergunta sobre isto em algum lugar que dá alguns parâmetros de como fazer).

Não sei se olhei todos os lados da questão mas é minha opinião no momento.

Answer (score 5):

Sou contra por estes motivos:

- A SE já disse que é válido continuar usando JS Fiddle e similares, e pos como alternativa ao usuário escolher o que quer usar, portanto, trata-se de opção pessoal e não de recomendação;
- a formatação em tela dos *snippets* da SE muitas vezes polui o post desnecessariamente, quando você quer uma resposta curta e objetiva, e o resultado é mero complemento. Uma resposta de 2 ou 3 linhas vira um bloco gigantesco, e a informação principal pode ficar perdida no meio do "demo";
- a pergunta tem que ser sempre muito clara, e é bem comum ser editada para refletir as recomendações de clareza e entendimento. Já as respostas, são de cunho um pouco mais pessoal, apesar de edição em qualquer coisa fazer parte das possibilidades, e justamente podemos ter várias, então edição deve ser feita para resolver problemas, e não atender gosto individual de alguém que não seja o autor;
- já vi situação em que o código ficou duplicado na página depois da edição, por descuido de quem fez a migração. Além da questão da interferência no "pessoalismo" da resposta, o acabamento final da resposta pode não refletir necessariamante a qualidade que o autor gosta de por nas postagens.

  Pra piorar, a edição do ponto mencionado foi aprovada por dois outros usuários, o que agrava o problema do descuido.

  PS: neste último caso estou falando de migração do JS Fiddle para o SOpt.

Acho que este tipo de mudança merece no máximo uma sugestão nos comments, e de preferência que seja apagada depois de lida, senão daqui a pouco vamos estar querendo padronizar estilo de formatação e indentação de código alheia também.